# Empty TextField if Statement

Tags: if-statement

If I want to make an if statement where it checks if the textfield is empty,  how do I do it?

I tried this;

```
if(jTextField4.getText().equals(""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) to check :

```
if(StringUtils.isEmpty(jTextField4.getText())
```

This will check if the String is null or empty with trimming the string.

If you do not like 3rd party library:

try this

```
String s = jTextField4.getText();
if(s != null && s.trim().equals(""))
```

So also all inputs that only contains blank are "empty".

Comment: In the if statement is it "StingUtils" or "StringUtils". I tried both and they both give an error!

Comment: It gives me an error in the method .isEmpty()

It says it can't find symbol.

Comment: @DuarteSaraiva Do you have downloaded the commons-lang.jar and added it to your classpath?

Comment: Don't worry about it! I used your second way and it worked :)